Keyboard shortcut (Cntrl 1-7) not working on my Macbook Air (2015), how do I fix this?
I used this shortcut (Cntrl 1-7) on another Mac laptop once, but for some reason, it doesn't work on mine (2015 Macbook Air), and I can't figure out how to fix it. I am a photographer and want to use it to put the color tags on pictures while I'm viewing a lot at a time.

It would be helpful if you added the version of macOS you are using and what specific app you are using to "put the color tags on pictures" without that basic information we will likely not be able to assist you.

@SteveChambers - it's a mechanism built into Finder itself. AFAIK, it has no control panel of any sort, it 'just works'. skyler - it's also the default key command set for swapping Spaces. Check that's not also enabled. Please also confirm you are in Finder when doing this, it may not work in other apps.

You can see if any other app is using Control + 1-7 causing conflict at System Preferences - Keyboard - Shortcuts, and if not you can create a shortcut you want yourself at App Shortcuts. Choose Finder and assign Control + 1-7 to the color tags manually if it’s not listed.
Also check your Finder - Preferences - Tags, check if color tags you want are enabled and listed.
Try updating macOS and if nothing helps reset Finder preferences, open Terminal and type: rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
and restart Finder by killall Finder
Let us know if anything helps!
